# Using Predicate to simplify multiple conditions

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following method which works fine. But it has multple if / else

logic going on in there and there is likely going to be an additional few more if/else logic that needs to be added soon.

Is there a way I could write this more elegantly, possibly by using Predicate instead?

To note: replaceFunction is a functional interface I wrote myself with the method apply in it.

It takes in 3 Strings and return a String based on some logic.

```
private String getLabel(String endDate, Map<String, Object> details) {
    LocalDate offerEndDate = LocalDate.parse(endDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    LocalDate currentDate = ZonedDateTime.now(clock).withZoneSameInstant(zoneId).toLocalDate();
    long numberOfDays = DAYS.between(currentDate, offerEndDate);

    // can't use switch cos numberOfDays is long and don't want to perform any downcasting to an int just for that. 
    if (numberOfDays > 20) {
        return replaceFunction.apply((String)details.get("EXPIRY_DATE"), "~EXPIRY_DATE~", offerEndDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yy")));
    } else if (numberOfDays > 13) {
        return replaceFunction.apply((String)details.get("EXPIRY_DAYS"), "~NO_OF_DAYS~", String.valueOf(numberOfDays));
    } else if (numberOfDays == 2) {
        return (String)details.get("EXPIRES_TOMORROW");
    } else if (numberOfDays == 1) {
        return (String)details.get("LAST_EXPIRY_DAY");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I could write this more elegantly, possibly by using Predicate instead?

I think the answer is No.

You could have dealt with the problem of the cast of a `long` to an `int` being lossy by testing that the value of `numberOfDays` is in the range `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` before casting to an `int`.

Or you could have observed that 2<sup>31</sup> days is a really long time.  About 5.8 million years.  I don't think that an "offer" needs to be open that long.

But I don't think a Java `switch` statement would be an improvement here anyway.  (A `switch` cannot express ranges elegantly.)

There will always be things that you cannot express in a concise / elegant way in the programming language that you are using.  My advice is to just accept that ... and write (if necessary) inelegant code that does the job<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - The real purpose of code is to perform a function, not to be beautiful.  My late father was a civil engineering lecturer.  In his office at uni, he had a small sign thumb-tacked to one of his bookcase.  It said "Time is Money".  Good engineers are pragmatic, and that includes software engineers.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map lookup when you use a `NavigableMap` which knows the natural order of the keys and therefore can return the associated value for, e.g. an “equal or lower” relation.

```java
static TreeMap<Long,BiFunction<LocalDate,Map<String, Object>,String>> LABELS = new TreeMap<>();
static {
    LABELS.put(1L, (d,m) -> (String)m.get("LAST_EXPIRY_DAY"));
    LABELS.put(2L, (d,m) -> (String)m.get("EXPIRES_TOMORROW"));
    LABELS.put(3L, (d,m) -> replaceFunction.apply((String)m.get("EXPIRY_DAYS"),
            "~NO_OF_DAYS~", String.valueOf(DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(clock), d))));
    LABELS.put(20L, (d,m) -> replaceFunction.apply((String)m.get("EXPIRY_DATE"),
            "~EXPIRY_DATE~", d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yy"))));
}
private String getLabel(String endDate, Map<String, Object> details) {
    LocalDate offerEndDate = LocalDate.parse(endDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    LocalDate currentDate = ZonedDateTime.now(clock).withZoneSameInstant(zoneId).toLocalDate();
    long numberOfDays = DAYS.between(currentDate, offerEndDate);
    return LABELS.floorEntry(numberOfDays).getValue().apply(offerEndDate, details);
}
```

Note that I changed the key values. Your original code does not handle values from three to twelve which can’t be intentional. With the `floorEntry` there can’t be any gaps; if I used the keys `1`, `2`, `13`, and `20`, all values from `2` to `12` would have been handled the same way. But obviously, the intent is to use the number of days from three upwards, until switching to a date.

I changed the handler code to repeat the `DAYS.between(...)` operation, to be able to use standard interfaces only. You seem to have a three-arg interface, so you could change to that interface and pass the already known number of days as function argument instead.

As another note, apparently you want to detach the code from the user messages, perhaps localize the messages, which is the good thing. Using the hard-coded date format `MM-dd-yy` is counter-acting the intent and can make things worse, e.g when showing a correctly translated message together with the non-localized date format where people are used to `dd-MM-yy` instead.

Maybe you can combine the `details` map with the other map, passing a map of formatting functions to the `getLabel` method.

Comment: Yes.  But when you compare this version to the original code, would you say that it is an improvement?

Comment: Not in this form (though I’d leave it up to the reader). As said in the answer, I’d try to merge such a map to formatting functions with the incoming parameter, i.e. the `Map<String, Object> details`. Perhaps, even get rid of the `replaceFunction` which seems to be a `String::replace` in disguise. With all of them combined, the parameter would not only control the messages but also the thresholds, which would be reasonable, as other cultures do not only use different languages and date formats, but may also have other preferences regarding when to use which simplified form.